# Calculus, function that has fractured derivative

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry

I have a function which has fractured derivative at $x=0$. How can i prove that it really has fractured derivative at $x=0$. Here is my function
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
x^2 \sin(1/x), & x \ne 0, \\
0, & x=0
\end{cases}
$$.

Comment: Do you mean discontinuous derivative?

Comment: What is a fractured derivative?

Comment: I think the OP means a derivative coming from different branches of definition of the function.

Comment: Yes, it has discontinuous derivative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Computing $$\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}=\frac{f(h)}{h}=h\sin(1/h)$$ and $$|h\sin(1/h)|\le |h|$$ and this tends to zero for $h$ tends to zero.

Comment: Yes this have i considered

Comment: Since $x_0=0$ was your problem